# Fim do overflow longe da tabela

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma tabela com `style="overflow: auto;`, só que o scroll fica lá em baixo, quase 1 dedo longe da tabela.

```html
<div style="overflow: scroll; height: 240px; width: 1000px;">
    <table border="1" class="table table-bordered" id="tabela" style="background-color: white;"> 
                            
         <tr>
             <h5>Usuários</h5>
         </tr>
                            
         <tr>
             <th>Nome</th>
             <th>Nome</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>João</td>
             <td>Maria</td>
         </tr>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Segue o print:

[image: Print]

Comment: Mas não é só diminuir o **height** da div??

Comment: Não, a tabela diminui, mas o scroll fica lá em baixo ainda.

Comment: Se for só pra 'tirar' o scroll quando o mesmo não é necessário é só utilizar `overflow: auto` (você está usando `scroll`)

Comment: Vc quer manter o scroll horizontal? Há a necessidade dele?

Comment: Não há necessidade do horizontal, ele está ali por estar.

Comment: E eu preciso deixar o a tabela nesse tamanho do height

Answer (score 0):

É só retirar o height fixo da sua tabela, sem ele o overflow estará sempre embaixo da tabela

```html
<div style="overflow: scroll;width: 1000px">
    <table border="1" class="table table-bordered" id="tabela" style="background-color: white;"> 
                            
         <tr>
             <h5>Usuários</h5>
         </tr>
                            
         <tr>
             <th>Nome</th>
             <th>Nome</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>João</td>
             <td>Maria</td>
         </tr>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```